# Generic type parameter with constraints from unsigned integer type

Tags: rust

I am trying to use a generic datatype which implements 2 methods from the unsigned primitive integer types in rust (u8, u32, u64, etc.). The goal is to be able to read some predefined datatype from a stream ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9d69d5970e4219ceb9819f81a86c5f9c)):

```
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::BufReader;

pub trait ReadExt {
    fn read<T>(&mut self) -> Result<T, std::io::Error>;
}

impl<R: Read> ReadExt for R {

    fn read<T>(&mut self) -> Result<T, std::io::Error> {
        let mut v = Vec::with_capacity((T::BITS >> 3).into());
        self.read_exact(&mut v);
        Ok(T::from_le_bytes(v))
    }
    
}

fn main() {
    let mut stream = BufReader::new(&0xffffffffu32.to_le_bytes()[..]);
    
    let x = ReadExt::read::<u32>(&mut stream).unwrap();
    
    assert_eq!(x, 0xffffffffu32);
}
```

I get the compile error:

```
error[E0599]: no associated item named `BITS` found for type parameter `T` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:11:44
   |
11 |         let mut v = Vec::with_capacity((T::BITS >> 3).into());
   |                                            ^^^^ associated item not found in `T`

error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `from_le_bytes` found for type parameter `T` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:13:15
   |
13 |         Ok(T::from_le_bytes(v))
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `T`
```

How do I add constraints on `T` and specify that `T` must implement the traits from u8, u16, u32? Specifically, I want `T` to implement [`BITS`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#associatedconstant.BITS) and [`from_le_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.from_le_bytes).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use any methods or constants coming from `T`, then `T` must be bounded/constrained by some trait, because you can use only methods/constants/etc coming from the trait bounds.

In your case that would be:

```
pub trait FromLeBytes {
    const BITS: u32;

    fn from_le_bytes(bytes: [u8; 4]) -> Self;
}
```

which defines the required method `from_le_bytes()` and the constant `BITS`.

You will have to implement that trait for each type that you want to use. Currently I've implemented it only for `u32`:

```
impl FromLeBytes for u32 {
    const BITS: u32 = u32::BITS;

    fn from_le_bytes(bytes: [u8; 4]) -> Self {
        u32::from_le_bytes(bytes)
    }
}
```

Then you need to declare that constraint by modifying your `ReadExt` trait:

```
pub trait ReadExt {
    fn read<T: FromLeBytes>(&mut self) -> Result<T, std::io::Error>;
}
```

After which you are ready to use the method and the constant in your code:

```rust
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::Read;

pub trait FromLeBytes {
    const BITS: u32;

    fn from_le_bytes(bytes: [u8; 4]) -> Self;
}

impl FromLeBytes for u32 {
    const BITS: u32 = u32::BITS;

    fn from_le_bytes(bytes: [u8; 4]) -> Self {
        u32::from_le_bytes(bytes)
    }
}

pub trait ReadExt {
    fn read<T: FromLeBytes>(&mut self) -> Result<T, std::io::Error>;
}

impl<R: Read> ReadExt for R {
    fn read<T: FromLeBytes>(&mut self) -> Result<T, std::io::Error> {
        // Could NOT have been done like that because of: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/68436
        // let mut v = [0; T::BITS as usize / 8];
        // self.read_exact(&mut v);
        // Ok(T::from_le_bytes(v))

        let mut v = Vec::with_capacity(T::BITS as usize / 8);
        v.resize(v.capacity(), 0);
        self.read_exact(&mut v).unwrap();

        let mut a = [0; 4];
        for (i, b) in v.iter().copied().enumerate() {
            a[i] = b;
        }
        Ok(T::from_le_bytes(a))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = &0xffffffffu32.to_le_bytes()[..];
    let mut stream = BufReader::new(x);

    let x = ReadExt::read::<u32>(&mut stream).unwrap();

    assert_eq!(x, 0xffffffffu32);
}
```

PS: I've also fixed some compilation errors in your original code

Comment: Thanks, although this seems to require implementing  ```FromLeBytes``` for u8, u16 etc. if i want to use ```ReadExt::read::<u8>(&mut stream).unwrap()```. In that case it might be cleaner just to write them as separate methods like ```read_u8```, ```read_u16```, ```read_u32```, etc.

Comment: Well, you cannot avoid implementing the trait for each type, but there are only a few types, so it's not a big deal. You can use a macro to do it like the standard library does, which will turn it into a one-liner , but I cannot help you with it. Macros are beyond my understanding :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not easily possible because `BITS` and `from_le_bytes` are both not from a trait, but associated functions of `u8`, `u16` etc. There is no common trait that has those functions/consts.

You can partially work around this by relying on [`num_traits::int::PrimInt::from_le()`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.2.14/num_traits/int/trait.PrimInt.html#tymethod.from_le) to convert endianness and [`std::mem::size_of()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html) to get the number of bytes in the integer. However, `from_le()` only allows converting an existing integer – it does **not** allow to convert a byte buffer, and your use case needs that.

If you are okay with using unsafe Rust, you can achieve what you want via [`std::mem::transmute_copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute_copy.html). Below you find code doing exactly that (I also fixed a few bugs in your original code). But please read on – there is still a subtle problem.

```rust
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::BufReader;
use num_traits::int::PrimInt;

pub trait ReadExt {
    fn read<T: PrimInt>(&mut self) -> Result<T, std::io::Error>;
}

impl<R: Read> ReadExt for R {
    fn read<T: PrimInt>(&mut self) -> Result<T, std::io::Error> {
        let mut v = vec![0u8; std::mem::size_of::<T>()];
        self.read_exact(&mut v).unwrap();
        let result_in_le: T = unsafe {
            std::mem::transmute_copy(&v[0])
        };
        Ok(T::from_le(result_in_le))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let buf = 0xffffffffu32.to_le_bytes();
    let mut stream = BufReader::new(&buf[..]);
    
    let x = ReadExt::read::<u32>(&mut stream).unwrap();
    
    assert_eq!(x, 0xffffffffu32);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d2d5a6645e0b311a4aa75780dd540e70)

This implementation has a way for the user to trigger undefined behavior: As `PrimInt` is not [sealed](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/future-proofing.html#sealed-traits-protect-against-downstream-implementations-c-sealed), one could implement the trait on some custom struct containing a `f64`. Using `ReadExt::read()`, one could then transform arbitrary byte patterns into a `f64` – this triggers undefined behavior.

To solve this, we can construct our own trait that is a subtrait of `PrimInt` and unsafe:

```rust
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::BufReader;
use num_traits::int::PrimInt;

pub unsafe trait UnsafeInt: PrimInt {
    
}

unsafe impl UnsafeInt for u8 {}
unsafe impl UnsafeInt for u16 {}
unsafe impl UnsafeInt for u32 {}
unsafe impl UnsafeInt for u64 {}
unsafe impl UnsafeInt for usize {}
unsafe impl UnsafeInt for i8 {}
unsafe impl UnsafeInt for i16 {}
unsafe impl UnsafeInt for i32 {}
unsafe impl UnsafeInt for i64 {}
unsafe impl UnsafeInt for isize {}

pub trait ReadExt {
    fn read<T: UnsafeInt>(&mut self) -> Result<T, std::io::Error>;
}

impl<R: Read> ReadExt for R {
    fn read<T: UnsafeInt>(&mut self) -> Result<T, std::io::Error> {
        let mut v = vec![0u8; std::mem::size_of::<T>()];
        self.read_exact(&mut v).unwrap();
        let result_in_le: T = unsafe {
            std::mem::transmute_copy(&v[0])
        };
        Ok(T::from_le(result_in_le))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let buf = 0xffffffffu32.to_le_bytes();
    let mut stream = BufReader::new(&buf[..]);
    
    let x = ReadExt::read::<u32>(&mut stream).unwrap();
    
    assert_eq!(x, 0xffffffffu32);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=49de69a1e96a105f1d34d5fe6d9842de)

This guarantees that `T` is a primitive type, thereby making the `transmute_copy` sound.